# Calculate number of 100-nanosecond ticks since 12:00 midnight, January 1, 0001 A.D. (C.E.) in the Gregorian Calendar

Tags: c++, boost

Can somebody help me calculate 100-nanosecond ticks since 12:00 midnight, January 1, 0001 A.D. (C.E.) in the Gregorian Calendar

Let's say the date is 2014-08-25 16:00:00.221.

This is what I tried, is this correct?

```
#include <boost/date_time/microsec_time_clock.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/local_time/local_time.hpp>

using namespace boost::gregorian;
using namespace boost::local_time;
using namespace boost::posix_time;

__int64 GetTicks( const string& dateTimeStr )
{
    ptime epoch = time_from_string("1970-01-01 00:00:00.000");
    ptime other = time_from_string(dateTimeStr.c_str());

    time_duration const diff = other - epoch;
    long long ms = diff.total_milliseconds();
    ms *= 10000LL;
    return static_cast<__int64>(ms) + 621355968000000000;
}
```

Comment: Well, does it perform the required task?

Comment: @lightness I doubt it, unless it contacts the net: at that resolution, the chaotic drag of the moon/earthquakes/weather/etc on the Earth will render any non-connected algorithm inaccurate reasonably quickly.  http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second  Maybe gregorian does not care?

Comment: @Yakk: I was hoping to encourage the OP to think about my question.

Comment: Can someone help me verify the logic, I referred to a sample implementation of GetTicks(), I  doubt about it.

Comment: Can someone help me verify the logic. Come on! No takers!!

Comment: I already told you why your problem as described is not solvable without an internet connection to external data (or, I suppose, access to telescopes).  I would advise against messing with time, there are few valid reasons to need what you asked for, and each of them are going to have further complicafions your question does not address.

Comment: @Yakk (out of curiosity) if the computer is connected to the internet ( it seems to be as he writes on stack overflow ) will the posix time of the machine not be properly adjusted ?